# How can I insert my Stack Overflow flair in a Word document?

Tags: support, meta, flair

I have checked on Stack Overflow some flairs with my info. I want to add them into my CV (MS Word Document), but there is no option to explain how I can add flair into my Word document.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is something preventing you from downloading the flair image to your computer?

Comment: Is it funny if I close vote this as off topic -> Migrate to Super User?

Comment: @rene, Meta does have some kind of a "first-level support" role. Let's not bother the SU folks with this, [they're above that level](http://superuser.com/q/621364/94017).

Comment: I wouldn't add a badge to a printed CV, but the URL to my profile.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is how you would do that:

- go to your [flair page](https://stackexchange.com/users/5236527/imran-qamer?tab=flair)
- copy the url that is in the src attribute of the `<img` tag
- goto Word
- Choose Insert Image
- Paste the Url
- Click Insert

You flair is now in the Word document

[image: a picture explains it better]

As your flair changes over time you might consider adding a macro to reduce the number of steps needed:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
    Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
        "https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5236527.png", LinkToFile:=False, _
        SaveWithDocument:=True
End Sub
```

I leave it to you to have this macro run automatically to update or replace the flair in your CV.

Comment: I created a CV with the macro, printed it out and now the flair is no longer updating. -1

Answer (score 4):

This is clearly a matter of preference and opinion, but I'd argue against doing this in the first place in many cases.

A screen shot of your badge is going to be permanently outdated, and might look very out of place, perhaps even a tad unprofessional, in a CV.

It also doesn't provide the reader with a way to actually check up on your profile, so you'll have to provide an additional URL.

I personally would just use the URL to the profile (or careers page) instead, and if it's needed, mention the reputation count as of the moment that you're writing the CV.

What also might be cool is linking to specific answers that show a skill that is needed in the context of the job application.

But then, of course, your mileage may vary. You may be applying in a highly competitive market with many more applicants than jobs, where huge piles of applications are weeded out quickly with little regard to individual detail. Visual recognition of the badge could help your application stand out. Just be thoughtful about it.